# Regex Class With Exceptions

Tags: regex

I know that the regex class `\D` matches "all characters that are non-numeric" but I would like to **match on all characters that are non-numeric and are not `/` or `-`**

How might I do this? Thanks!

Comment: Be it for JavaScript or any other language, ndn's answer is "the best". In Java, you could use `[\\D&&[^/-]]`, in .NET `[\D-[/-]]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can negate character sets by putting `^` inside:

```
[^\d\/-]
```

Will match any one character, which is **not** a *digit*, *forward slash* or *dash*.

Answer (score 0):

You already know how to find non-numeric characters with `\D`. You may lay a restriction on the `\D` to exclude `/` and `-` and any other non-numeric characters with a [negative lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
(?![\/-])\D
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/jWoBAc/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [\/-]                    any character of: '\/', '-'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \D                       non-digits (all but 0-9)
```